# WPF datagrid change color when text change

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, colors

I want to change the color of the cell in a datagrid when the user changes the text or content of that cell.

I am using WPF an C#.

I have a simple datagrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Horreos}" KeyDown="dataGrid1_KeyDown" SelectedCellsChanged="dataGrid1_SelectedCellsChanged"> <DataGrid.Columns > </DataGrid.Columns> </DataGrid>
```

This events: keydown and selectedcellschange are tests for change my color cell. In the .cs I tried changing the cel.... but I failed.

**I need an event that is released when the content changes**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code. Check  this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) on how to write and ask a good question.

Comment: Add your code on the question, not as a comment. Use the **edit** link on the lower left corner of the question, below the tags list.

Answer (score 0):

Set a behavior, the easiest way is using Blend. I provide an example against a datagrid on my blog article: [Xaml: Adding Visibility Behaviors Using Blend to A DataGrid for WPF or Silverlight](http://omegacoder.com/?tag=behavior)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

```
 private void dataGrid1_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridCell gridCell = null;
        try
        {
            gridCell = GetCell(dataGrid1.SelectedCells[0]);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        if (gridCell != null)
            gridCell.Background = Brushes.Red;

    }
public  DataGridCell GetCell(DataGridCellInfo dataGridCellInfo)
    {
        if (!dataGridCellInfo.IsValid)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var cellContent = dataGridCellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(dataGridCellInfo.Item);
        if (cellContent != null)
        {
            return (DataGridCell)cellContent.Parent;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

private void MyDataGrid_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGrid grid = sender as DataGrid;
        e.Row.MouseEnter += (s, args) => Row_MouseEnter(s, grid);
        e.Row.MouseLeave += (s, args) => Row_MouseLeave(s, grid);
    }

    void Row_MouseLeave(object sender, DataGrid grid)
    {
        DataGridRow row = sender as DataGridRow;
        grid.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    void Row_MouseEnter(object sender, DataGrid grid)
    {
        DataGridRow row = sender as DataGridRow;
        grid.SelectedIndex = row.GetIndex();

    }
```

When the user finishes editing the cell turns red.

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" 
                     Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=Source}" LoadingRow="MyDataGrid_LoadingRow"  CellEditEnding="dataGrid1_CellEditEnding">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
```